# UCP алгоритм работы

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle-ucp

Работаю с Universal connection pool от оракла. Работаю по такой схеме

```
class Action {
  static PoolDataSource initPool() {
    PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
    pds.setURL(".........");
    pds.setUser("user");
    pds.setPassword("pass");
    pds.setInitialPoolSize(0);
    return pds;
  }

  static final PoolDataSource pds = initPool();

  void doAction() {
    Connection connection = pds.getConnection();
    ..........
    connection.close();  // ????
  }
}
```

Вопрос, нужно ли по завершению `doAction` вызывать `connection.close()` или от этого теряется весь смысл работы с пулом и соединения там должны оставаться открытыми, пока сами не закроются по таймауту?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950760/ucp-algorithm-of-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коннект нужно закрывать. Вызов `Connection.close()` не приводит к фактическому закрытию соединения, а служит сигналом для возвращения соединения в пул

Детали описаны в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/connect.htm#CHDJCGGB)

> Borrowed connections that are no longer being used should be returned to the pool so that they can be available for the next connection request. The close method is used to close connections and automatically returns the connections to the pool. The close method does not physically remove the connection from the pool.
>
> Borrowed connections that are not closed will remain borrowed; subsequent requests for a connection result in a new connection being created if no connections are available. This behavior can cause many connections to be created and can affect system performance.

> Взятое соединение, которое больше не нужно должно быть возвращено в пул, чтобы быть доступным для следующего запроса. Метод `close` используется для закрытия соединения и автоматического возвращения его в пул. Метод `close` физически не удаляет соединение из пула.
>
> Взятое соединение, которое не было закрыто остается используемым. Последующие запросы соединения приводят к созданию новых соединений, если в пуле больше не осталось соединений. Такое поведение может привести к созданию многих соединений и может повлиять на производительность системы.